# Back stack issue with widget

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, back

I have a widget that can launch two different activities, Activity A and Activity B, depending on which hot spot is clicked. What I would like to have is to reset the back stack when launching each activity. The problem is the following:

1. I click hot spot 1 and launch Activity A
2. I press the Home button
3. I click hot spot 2 and launch Activity B
4. I press the back button and instead of going back to the home
   screen, I go back to Activity A

The way I launch the activities from the widget is the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

- Create a global Variables that changes when each Hot spot is clicked.
- Override Back Button
- inside the Back Button method, create a switch e.g.

  - CASE 1: // go back to home menu etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to both activities (it was only used in once of them). That fixed the problem easily.